# How to align my mathematical equation in Latex

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I am including several mathematical equations in my research work. So I am wondering how I can move the whole equation to the left, especially equation number 7.

[image]

The latex code that I used to generate it is :

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq7}
\begin{split}
I(W;G) = \\ { \sum_{g \in G}^{2} {max} \in (P_{WG}(W,G),0.001)} \times log
\frac{P_{WG(W,G)}}{P(G)P(W)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: General advice: use `\mathit` or `\operatorname` for long function names (e.g. `\mathit{FeatureScore}`) to avoid bad kerning.
Also, use the `\log` macro instead of just `log` to get appropriate fonts and spacing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 

\begin{equation} \label{eq7}
\begin{aligned}
  & I(W;G) = \\
  & \sum_{g \in G}^2 \max \bigl\{P_{WG}(W,G),0.001\bigr\} \times \log \frac{P_{WG(W,G)}}{P(G)P(W)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you AboAmmar for sharing the right usage of aligned.

Comment: But I tried it at another equation and did not aligned.  Can you try it ? ''\begin{equation} \label{eq11}
\begin{aligned}
MI(word;Gender)=\\
{\sum_{g \in Gender}^{2} P(word\&g)}
\times log \frac{max(P(word\&g),0.0001)} 
{\frac{AllCount(g)}{Allcount}
\times {P(word)}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}''

Comment: @Krebto : You forgot the alignment marks, `\begin{equation} \label{eq11} 
\begin{aligned} 
  &MI(word;Gender)=\\ 
  &{\sum_{g \in Gender}^{2} P(word\&g)} \times log \frac{max(P(word\&g),0.0001)} {\frac{AllCount(g)}{Allcount} \times {P(word)}} 
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}`, will be fine.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that I've replaced `{` and `}` with `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}`, respectively. I've also replaced `max` and `log` with `\max` and `\log`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran} % ??
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq7}
\begin{split}
I(W;G) &= \biggl\{ \sum_{g\in G} 
\max \bigl(P_{WG}(W,G),0.001\bigr) \biggr\} \\
&\qquad\times \log\frac{P_{WG}(W,G)}{P(G)P(W)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good. I used {aligned} instead of split and I got it in the right format. Thank you for your input